# What's a series of pictures called? Not montage, collage etc. — something from National Geographic

Tags: terminology, street-photography, storytelling

I'm not talking about a collage, montage, slideshow or any form of video or time-lapse. It's a word I had read on some page of the National Geographic site but  forgot.  The series tells a story of a place or something. It's not a usual word.

Comment: Theme, Motif, Trope?

Answer (score 2):

Could it be that you're thinking of a [photo-essay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photo-essay)?

Comment: Also see https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/462143/the-proper-name-for-a-story-with-photos